# Log4Net. Restrict RollingFileAppender to log events in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, rollingfileappender

We are using Log4Net version 2.0.8 for logging, and it is configured to log into files. RollingFileAppender is configured as appender. 
It loggs events perfectly into files, but we found that it loggs into Windows Event Log as well.
We are wondering is it possible somehow to turn off logging to Windows Event log

[image]

Below is the configuration of Log4Net

.net 4.7.1 is the version.

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
  </root>
  <logger name="zzzzzz
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="WarningAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="NServiceBus">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="WarningAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
  </logger>
```

```
  <appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <file value="C:\Logs\Product\\" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />

    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd\\\\'Product.Error.txt'" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5Mb" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <!-- No limit on roll backs -->
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <!-- Creates the folder for the day before logging for that day starts -->

    <layout type="zzzzz.MyOrders.Utilities.Logging.Log4Net.ExtendedPatternLayout, zzzzzz.MyOrders.Utilities.Logging">
      <conversionPattern value="Product.WebApi - %date [%thread] [%correlationId] %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="ERROR" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have maybe some unhandled Exception that are logged into the Windows Eventlog?

Comment: Thanks for attention. It's a little bit different. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

We found answer to question and are recognizing that the question is incorrect. So we have the wrapper for loggers encapsulated in nuget package, which wraps log4net and handwritten "EventLogLogger"

The client code in the wrapper is looks like

```
    private void WriteLogMessageToLogs(LogMessageType logMessageType, LogMessage logMessage)
    {         
        foreach (var loggingProvider in this.loggingProviders)
        {
            loggingProvider.AddLogEntry(logMessage, logMessageType);
        }
    }
```

So sorry for bothering all attendees, the Log4Net is not the one behind this.